# Python session.commit() updates existing row instead of inserting a new one

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am having an issue where I am looping through several rows of a CSV file and I need to insert a new row to my mySQL table at the end of every iteration of the for loop.  However, for some reason, sqlAlchemy is updating the previously existing row instead of inserting a new one.

I cannot share my specific code because my work doesn't allow me to, but it does the following

```
for row in csv_file:
    do stuff
    try:
      session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
      logging.info(e)
      session.rollback()
```

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just figured out what I was doing wrong, I wasn't instantiating my SQL model class at the beginning of every iteration.  It works now

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just figured out what I was doing wrong, I wasn't instantiating my SQL model class at the beginning of every iteration. It works now